# nvidia-settings fails on 20.04

Tags: graphics, 20.04

any solutions to this problem would be helpful. I am trying to toggle the settings so that when I am docked or perhaps on battery power, external monitors could be driven by the NVIDIA dGPU on my laptop. Currently, while using the iGPU to drive screens, I experience screen tearing.

```
sudo nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:276055): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 08:21:47.375: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 08:21:47.381: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 08:21:47.381: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia probably isn't recognized properly.

Did you "install third party software" during OS installation ?